# current post with current author

Tags: posts, users, id

how can i check if the current post belongs to the current author? this is my basic code;
`

```
if($curpost) {
                wpuf_edit_show_form($curpost);
            } else {
                $error = "there is no post.";
            }
```

`

also how can i add the same control to these action;
`

```
function wpuf_user_dashboard_post_list() {
    global $wpdb, $userdata;

    get_currentuserinfo(); // grabs the user info and puts into vars

    //delete post
    if ($_REQUEST['action'] == "del")
    {
        check_admin_referer('wpuf_del');
        wp_delete_post($_REQUEST['pid']);
        echo '<div class="success">deleted.</div>';
    }

    //get the posts
    $sql = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_name, post_status, post_date "
            . "FROM $wpdb->posts "
            . "WHERE post_author = $userdata->ID AND post_type = 'post' "
            . "AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'pending' OR post_status = 'draft') ";

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $count = 1;
    //d($posts);
```

`

thanks.

Comment: There are [dozens of Qs](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=current+author) about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compacted version that does not load the globals yet calls upon them directly.

```
if(
    is_user_logged_in() and // Force user validation... STUFF
    !empty($GLOBALS['post']) and // Check if a $post exists in globals
    !empty($GLOBALS['current_user']) and // Check if current_user exists in globals
    ($GLOBALS['current_user']->ID == $GLOBALS['post']->post_author) // Match User IDs
){
    // This is your Author speaking, use the Force!
}
```

Regards.